# How to verify signed XML document with including Certifying authority (chain)?

Tags: java, xml, cryptography, x509certificate, digital-signature

I am verifying signed XML files using standard code as below.

```
 boolean coreValidity = false;
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");       
    if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
        throw new XMLSignatureException("Cannot find Signature element");
    }
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    for(int itr = 0; itr < nl.getLength(); itr++){
        DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext
            (new KeyValueKeySelector(), nl.item(itr));
        XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
        KeyValueKeySelector keyValueKeySelector = new KeyValueKeySelector();
        DOMValidateContext docContext = new DOMValidateContext(keyValueKeySelector, doc.getDocumentElement());
        coreValidity = signature.validate(docContext);            
        if (coreValidity == false) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO ,"Signature failed");
             }
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO ,"Signature passed core validation");
        }
```

I need to verify the certificate chain including CA.
What code is required?

Comment: Have you seen [code sample 8 of Sean Mullan's blog post](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html)? Do read past the code!